# Terraform aws Provider issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue?

Initializing provider plugins...

- terraform.io/builtin/terraform is built in to Terraform
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 3.56.0"...
  ╷
  │ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
  │
  │ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
  │ hashicorp/aws: provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws was not found
  │ in any of the search locations
  │
  │   - /var/terraform/terraform-provider-aws-3.56.0/

```
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4096 Oct 15 03:21 terraform-provider-aws-3.56.0
[root@7c3369092d09 terraform]# pwd
/var/terraform
[root@7c3369092d09 terraform]#

[root@7c3369092d09 terraform]# cd terraform-provider-aws-3.56.0/
[root@7c3369092d09 terraform-provider-aws-3.56.0]# ll
total 572
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root 151552 Aug 26 22:30 aws
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root   4096 Aug 26 22:30 awsproviderlint
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 275106 Aug 26 22:30 CHANGELOG.md
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root   4096 Aug 26 22:30 docs
drwxr-xr-x. 27 root root   4096 Aug 26 22:30 examples
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   6140 Aug 26 22:30 GNUmakefile
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   1137 Aug 26 22:30 go.mod
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  62213 Aug 26 22:30 go.sum
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   4096 Aug 26 22:30 infrastructure
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  16725 Aug 26 22:30 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    580 Aug 26 22:30 main.go
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   2067 Aug 26 22:30 README.md
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   7105 Aug 26 22:30 ROADMAP.md
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 Aug 26 22:30 scripts
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     86 Aug 26 22:30 staticcheck.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 Aug 26 22:30 tools
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 Aug 26 22:30 version
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   4096 Aug 26 22:30 website
[root@7c3369092d09 terraform-provider-aws-3.56.0]#
```

I am using creating docker image/container to install the terraform and do the operation on it:
Docker file snippet:

## It will download the provider installer from our repo i.e. name terraform-provider-aws_3.56.0_linux_amd64

```
RUN wget $FILES_REPO_LOCAL/sd.svtstand.files/distributive/terraform/providers/terraform-provider-aws_${PROVIDER_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip \
    && unzip terraform-provider-aws_*.zip -d /tmp \
    && rm terraform-provider-aws_*.zip \
    && mkdir -p /opt/terraform/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/${PROVIDER_VERSION}/linux_amd64 \
    && mv /tmp/terraform-provider-aws_* /opt/terraform/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/${PROVIDER_VERSION}/linux_amd64 \
    && chmod 775 /opt/terraform/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/${PROVIDER_VERSION}/linux_amd64
```

## This will initialize the terraform

```
terraform init -plugin-dir=/opt/terraform/plugins
```

```
#Provider block

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
       source = "hashicorp/aws"
       version = ">=3.35.0"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output:
2021-10-18T13:47:01.766Z [DEBUG] will search for provider plugins in [/opt/terraform/plugins] Initializing provider plugins... - terraform.io/builtin/terraform is built in to Terraform - Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 3.62.0"... - Installing hashicorp/aws v3.62.0...

Output in the container: [root@bf34ab9c5277 aws]# pwd /opt/terraform/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws

[root@bf34ab9c5277 aws]# ll
total 0 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 25 Oct 18 12:59 3.62.0
[root@bf34ab9c5277 aws]#

Comment: What is the output of `terraform -version`? Have you carried out any Terraform upgrades, specifically from 0.12 to 0.13 recently?

Comment: What is your `required_providers` nested block?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary:  $ terraform --version
Terraform v1.0.0

Comment: @MattSchuchard:
    aws = {
PROVIDER_VERSION=3.62.0

Comment: @user3382387 Please provide the full terraform config for a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary : I have added the details in the problem statement sir. Any help please?

Comment: I am able to fix the issue. It was an issue of AWS provider executables which I downloaded from terraform.